# What is wrong with this MySQL trigger for ranking?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger that ranks all the entries in a table from 1 to 10 (with the maximum value having rank 10, the minimum value having rank 1, and all others are assigned integer values in between). Here is the trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER risks_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON risks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE n_project_id integer; #project_id associated with risk
DECLARE max_cost double; #previous maximum expected_cost in project
DECLARE min_cost double; #previous minimum expected_cost in project
DECLARE max_impact double; #previous maximum impact_effect in project
DECLARE min_impact double; #previous minimum impact_effect in project
DECLARE slope double; #slope for prioritizing function

SELECT t.project_id INTO n_project_id FROM tasks t WHERE t.task_id = NEW.task_id; #GET PROJECT_ID ASSOCIATED WITH THE RISK

SET NEW.expected_cost = NEW.probability * NEW.cost_impact, NEW.overall_impact = NEW.probability * NEW.impact_effect; #CALCULATE EXPECTED_COST AND OVERALL_IMPACT FIELDS

SELECT MAX(expected_cost), MIN(expected_cost), MAX(overall_impact), MIN(overall_impact) INTO max_cost, min_cost, max_impact, min_impact FROM view_risks WHERE r.project_id = n_project_id; #GET EXTREME VALUES FROM TABLE, STORE IN MEMORY

/*
Update Priority Monetary Rankings
*/
IF (max_cost IS NULL OR min_cost IS NULL) THEN #check for empty table
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
ELSEIF ((NEW.expected_cost <= max_cost) AND (NEW.expected_cost >= min_cost)) THEN 
#NEW VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE TABLE EXTREMES
    IF (max_cost - min_cost = 0) THEN
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    ELSE
        SET slope = 9 / (max_cost - min_cost);
SET NEW.priority_monetary = slope * (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
    END IF;
ELSEIF (NEW.expected_cost > max_cost) THEN
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    SET slope = 9 / (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - min_cost) + 1 WHERE project_id = n_project_id;
ELSE #NEW VALUE CORRESPONDS TO A MINIMUM
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 1;
    SET slope = 9 / (max_cost - NEW.expected_cost);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - min_cost) + 1 WHERE project_id = n_project_id;
END IF;

/*
Update Priority Effect Rankings
*/
IF (max_impact IS NULL OR min_impact IS NULL) THEN #check for empty table
    SET NEW.priority_effect = 10;
ELSEIF ((NEW.overall_impact <= max_impact) AND (NEW.overall_impact >= min_impact)) THEN 
#NEW VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE TABLE EXTREMES
    IF (max_cost - min_cost = 0) THEN
        SET NEW.priority_effect = 10;
    ELSE
        SET slope = 9 / (max_impact - min_impact);
SET NEW.priority_effect = slope * (NEW.overall_impact - min_impact) + 1;
    END IF;
ELSEIF (NEW.overall_impact > max_impact) THEN
    SET NEW.priority_effect = 10;
    SET slope = 9 / (NEW.overall_impact - min_impact);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_effect = slope * (overall_impact - min_impact) + 1 WHERE project_id = n_project_id;
ELSE #NEW VALUE CORRESPONDS TO A MINIMUM
    SET NEW.priority_effect = 1;
    SET slope = 9 / (max_impact - NEW.overall_impact);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_effect = slope * (overall_impact - min_impact) + 1 WHERE project_id = n_project_id;
END IF;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong? For your reference, my ranking algorithm is described by the following function with constants maxval and minval:

Rank(x) = 1 + slope(x - minval), where slope = 9/(maxval - minval).

Thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Field Types:
expected_cost => decimal(11,2)
priority_monetary => tinyint(2)

Sample values:
expected_cost => 1000.00
priority_monetary => 2

Comment: Can you provide the schema and sample dataset for the tables included in trigger ,for your syntax error i have formatted the trigger syntax and i found no issue

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got ELSE IF where you should use ELSEIF.

Also as @Mihai wrote : your minuses don't appear as minuses, and you have keyword TABLE after UPDATE (there should be only UPDATE tableName).

**PS** I recommend you to use some tool for MySql such as [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), it has distribution for Windows, most linux systems and OSX. It will make you work nicer and check your syntax.

Your code after changes:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER risks_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON risks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE max_cost double; #previous maximum expected_cost in project
DECLARE min_cost double; #previous minimum expected_cost in project
DECLARE slope double; #slope for prioritizing functioN

SELECT MAX(expected_cost), MIN(expected_cost) INTO max_cost, min_cost FROM view_risks; #GET EXTREME VALUES FROM TABLE, STORE IN MEMORY

/*
Update Priority Monetary Rankings
*/
IF (max_cost IS NULL OR min_cost IS NULL) THEN #check for empty table
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
ELSEIF ((NEW.expected_cost <= max_cost) AND (NEW.expected_cost >= min_cost)) THEN #NEW VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE TABLE EXTREMES
    IF (max_cost - min_cost = 0) THEN
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    ELSE
        SET slope = 9 / (max_cost - min_cost);
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = slope * (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
    END IF;
ELSEIF (NEW.expected_cost > max_cost) THEN
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    SET slope = 9 / (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
ELSE #NEW VALUE CORRESPONDS TO A MINIMUM
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 1;
    SET slope = 9 / (max_cost - NEW.expected_cost);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - NEW.min_cost) + 1;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the minus signs, and I also fixed the UPDATE TABLE syntax. However, the code that I posted was actually a portion of the entire trigger, I only included that part to make it simpler. However, I am still getting an error, likely due to one of the other small adjustments you made. Could you please take a look at the entire trigger code? I edited the above post and error message to include it.

Comment: I also fixed the ELSEIF and still have the same problem mentioned above.

Comment: now you don't have $$ after last END.
Use some MySql tool as [http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/]

Comment: That was a mistake. I found the error; it turns out I referred to the variable min_cost as NEW.min)cost. I edited it in the above code to remove this problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: seems legit. 
PS as i wrote, do yourself a favor and install MySqlWorkbench or some other free tool

Answer (score 1):

In my MySql client your minuses didn't appear as minuses,also did some minor modifications(UPDATE tableName without the keyword TABLE)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER risks_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON risks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE max_cost double; #previous maximum expected_cost in project
DECLARE min_cost double; #previous minimum expected_cost in project
DECLARE slope double; #slope for prioritizing functioN

SELECT MAX(expected_cost), MIN(expected_cost) INTO max_cost, min_cost FROM view_risks; #GET EXTREME VALUES FROM TABLE, STORE IN MEMORY

/*
Update Priority Monetary Rankings
*/
IF (max_cost IS NULL OR min_cost IS NULL) THEN #check for empty table
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
ELSE IF ((NEW.expected_cost <= max_cost) AND (NEW.expected_cost >= min_cost)) THEN #NEW VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE TABLE EXTREMES
    IF (max_costs - min_cost = 0) THEN
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    ELSE
        SET slope = 9 / (max_cost - min_cost);
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = slope * (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
    END IF;
ELSE IF (NEW.expected_cost > max_cost) THEN
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    SET slope = 9 / (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
ELSE #NEW VALUE CORRESPONDS TO A MINIMUM
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 1;
    SET slope = 9 / (max_cost - NEW.expected_cost);
    UPDATE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - NEW.min_cost) + 1;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the minus signs, and I also fixed the UPDATE TABLE syntax. However, the code that I posted was actually a portion of the entire trigger, I only included that part to make it simpler. However, I am still getting an error, likely due to one of the other small adjustments you made. Could you please take a look at the entire trigger code? I edited the above post and error message to include it.

Comment: check my answer below, you've got ELSE IF where you should use ELSEIF